# Unicode in powershell

Tags: powershell

I use this script

```
$old1 = 'Description'
$new1 = 'PLOT'
$old2 = 'Fantastic'
$new2 = 'Brilliant'

$config1s = Get-ChildItem


get-childitem C:\Users\user\Desktop\Powershell -recurse -include *.nfo | 
 select -expand fullname |
  foreach {
            (Get-Content $_) -replace $old1,$new1 | 
             Set-Content $_
            }


get-childitem C:\Users\user\Desktop\Powershell -recurse -include *.nfo | 
 select -expand fullname |
  foreach {
            (Get-Content $_) -replace $old2,$new2 | 
             Set-Content $_
            }
```

To replace the word Description with plot and the word Fantastic to Brilliant.

however i need to insert Unicode ═ after the words afterwards.. I've read through some other questions and it worked with inserting `TM` but cant get it to work with this icon.

Icon = http://www.codetable.net/decimal/9552

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Does inserting `[char]9552` not work?
Also, Set-Content has an Encoding option. In order to get a unicode character in a text file you must ensure the file is using the proper encoding for it.
Try using `Set-Content $_ -Encoding UTF8`.
Since your code overwrites the files I would also suggest adding the `-Force` option to the Set-Content command.

Comment: Hi Theo thank you.

But it doesnt seem to work, atleast when i do it. can you somehow add it to my code?

Comment: Hi Morten. Since i don't have an example of your original .nfo, i would suggest simply adding the character to the replacement strings like $old1 = 'Description'
$new1 = 'PLOT' + [char]9552
$old2 = 'Fantastic'
$new2 = 'Brilliant' + [char]9552

Comment: And ofcourse use Set-Content $_ -Encoding UTF8 -Force
(sorry for the bad formatting here..)